# Chained MySQL replication from Master->Master replicated pair

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.6, multi-master

This is a pictorial view of what I have:

```
Master 1<----->Master 2
|                     |
|                     |
V                     V
Slave 1         Slave 2
```

The masters are never written to at the same time, rather Master 2 is a standby server. Both Masters have `log-slave-updates` turned on in `my.cnf`.

If a table is created in a replicated DB on Master 1, it is present on Master 1, Master 2 and Slave 1. It is **NOT** present on Slave 2.

In the same way, if a table is created in a replicated DB on Master 2, it is present on Master 1, Master 2 and Slave 2. It is **NOT** present on Slave 1.

Why is this the case? Is it a limitation of MySQL in how it stops master/master replicated servers from creating replication loops if both have log-slave-updates turned on?

Is there a way this can work?

Comment: There is no such limitation in MySQL. Replication propagates changes through practically infinite amount of tiers. Did you check the server-ids? Do you have any replication or binlog filter?

Comment: server-id values are all different. I do have a `binlog_do_db` containing only one database. That database is the one the table is being created in.

Comment: That filter could easily be the problem. `binlog_do_db` has some limitations of what it can recognise (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#option_mysqld_binlog-do-db). Try to remove that and see if it works the way you want it. If you do need some filtering use `replication-do-db` on the slave instead. It's more advantageous from many perspective.

Comment: I changed binlog_format from MIXED to STATEMENT and that seems to have solved the problem. Going to do some more research...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, the "fix" is to change binlog_format to `STATEMENT`. It was previously `MIXED`.

Not entirely sure of the reason behind this - MySQL should be intelligent when using MIXED mode about what is replicated as statement and what is replicated as row.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have binlog/replicate filtering, this is probably what happened:

```
USE non_replicated_db;
CREATE TABLE replicated_db.table_name ...;
```

The filtering works on the `USE`, not on the db qualification in the statement.

(PS, you are using what is probably the best layout for standard replication: dual-master-single-writer, plus slaves hanging off both.  If the Masters are in different physical locations, it is even better.)